# How to decide which methods belong where? C++

Tags: c++

I finished writing an AVL tree, and one of the things that bothered me when programming it is deciding which methods belong to which class:

```
template <class ValueType,class CompareFunction>
class avlTree{
    class avlTreeException{};
public:
    class ElementDoesntExist : public avlTreeException{};
    class EmptyTree : public avlTreeException{};
    class ElementAlreadyExists : public avlTreeException{};
private:
    class Node{
        friend class avlTree;
        ValueType* data;
        Node *sonA,*sonB,*dad;
        int height,balance;
private:
CompareFunction compare;
int treeSize;
Node* root;
};
```

(I removed the public\private methods to save space).

For some methods I think I made the right choice: update is a method of Node (updates height,etc).

Insert/remove are functions of the tree.

But for example the function `destroyNodeTree(Node*)` which is used by the tree destructor. What I did is to have `destroyNodeList()` call `destroyNodeTree(root)`

```
template <class ValueType,class CompareFunction>
void avlTree<ValueType,CompareFunction>::avlTree::destroyNodeTree(Node* rooty) {
    if(!rooty){
        return;
    }
    Node *A=rooty->sonA,*B = rooty->sonB;
    destroyNodeTree(A);
    destroyNodeTree(B);
}
```

However, I could have made `destroyNodeTree()` a method of Node, and call it on the root from the destructor (it would be implemented in the same way).

I had a similar issue deciding where the method `findNode(const ValueType&)` should go, meaning it obviously is a public method of tree, but should I create a method for Node with the same name and have the tree function call the node method on the root? Is it even acceptable to have a public function and an inner class method with the same name?

In my opinion it's better to have it as a method of nodes because that gives more flexibility (I'll be able to search for a node only under a certain node), but on the other hand that means that the method either needs to create an instance of `class compare`, or have each node keep a copy of an instance, or have `class compare` as a static function. Each of those has a disadvantage in my opinion though: creating an instance can be costly, keeping a copy can be costly, and forcing the user to make the function static doesn't seem right to me (but I'm horribly inexperienced so fix me if I'm wrong).

In any case I eventually made findNode a treeFunction only and not a method (the HW assignment didn't need the tree to able to search from a specific node so it doesn't make any difference there) but I don't want to write bad code.

To conclude, how do we decide where to save performance,memory,flexibility of the user (would he rather be able to search from any node or create nonstatic compare functions?)

Comment: I know one thing, I am not reading all this and what is the reason behind having a class within a class? Did you mean to have an object that contains another class's object?

Comment: @FirstStep Sorry for the long question, I described the exact issues I faced, I'd appreciate an answer to the question asked in the title without the details I went into as well.

Comment: @FirstStep I don't understand what you're asking, can you clarify?